# Mapping Service to Appery.io HTML Component and Variables

Tags: appery.io

Is there a way to take a service that connects to an Appery database and map it to an HTML page component or a variable?

I have successfully set up a service that connects to my Appery.io database and I'm mapping it to a page.

I can get content into Text and Image components, but mapping a string to the HTML component doesn't seem to work, nor does mapping a string to a variable set up on that page (typed as a string). I tried mapping the $[i] object to the HTML object as well, but that didn't seem to change anything.

I tried mapping a couple different columns to the variable and the HTML component and even the ones that successfully map to other components don't result in any content showing on the page. As a way of trying to see what was going on, I used the "log value to console" transformation and nothing shows up in the console for the variable or HTML component.

Comment: Does your service return the HTML layout?
What project type do you use here? JQM or Ionic 5?

Comment: @SerhiiKulibaba Yes, everything looks correct in the service response on the actual page in the browser. This is an Ionic 5 project. Is the HTML element looking for any particular formatting before using the mapped response data or should it just be trying to display any string passed to it?

Comment: @SerhiiKulibaba I also notice that when nothing is mapped to the HTML component it displays in the browser as an empty <div>, but when something is mapped to it, it is not added to the page markup at all... The page code skips right to the next component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic mapping won't work for that purpose, so please use the following workaround:

1. Please add two custom includes (SafeHtml and DomSanitizer) and define variables, based on them:[image: see here details]
2. On the HTML component add the property [innerHtml]:

> [innerHtml]=value

3. Set the value to that variable with the custom code:

```
this.value = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<a href="https://appery.io">appery.io</a>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I set up the includes and variables as specified. I added the property [innerHtml], including the brackets. I set the attribute value to value. I wasn't sure where to add the code, so I mapped the string containing the html to the html component. Then I put that code in as a transformation of that mapping. That didn't work. Can you clarify where to run that code? I also don't understand how the html content gets into the sanitizer to be passed to "value", so maybe there's some stuff to do that I'm missing.

Comment: Please see the updated code on step #3.

Comment: I tried using the updated code in 3, but I might not be using it in the correct place. I tried running it in the mapping transformation for that field, thinking that's how I would feed it the HTML to replace the appery.io link test code, but that didn't do anything. Neither did running the code as a page event. So, could you let me know where exactly that code needs to go and also confirm how the string from the database should be inserted into this code. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Just test it with the static HTML code. Do you see the correct HTML layout or just text? Could you please show the screenshot of that page? WIth the static string, not the response from the database (You will replace it if it works fine with the static value)

Comment: Ok, this worked. I removed the mapping to that element, which I think was overwriting it. I tried a couple ways to get the value from the database into this, but none worked, so what is the process for that?

Comment: How exactly do you set that variable from the database? Do you run the function this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml after getting the variable from the database?

Comment: I tried mapping it to a variable and using that variable as the value passed to this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHTML, but that didn't work. Then I tried mapping to the variable but running this code as part of the mapping: this.cleanHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value); But that didn't work either. (cleanHtml is what I renamed the "value" variable everywhere. It was working before to display the appery.io link.) Can you suggest the best way to get the string of HTML content from the database into that bypassSecurityTrustHtml function?

Comment: Probably, you use incorrect HTML string there. Please show me the exact HTML code you use here?

Comment: I tried a few things where I set a default value for the variable and it was working like that but when I tried those same strings in the database and tried mapping to a variable it doesn't work. Even an HTML string like "<strong>test</strong>" doesn't work from the database. Maybe I'm not setting up the variable correctly for mapping. All I've done is create the variable in the Code tab (typed as a string) and then I map a string from the database to it. Then I run custom TS code like I mention in my previous comment.

Comment: Just tested it on my app. Everything works well. You are right, it seems something is wrong with that mapping. Could you please display it somewhere in the label to be sure it contains the correct HTML layout?

Comment: Can you show me how you set up the variable and mapped a value from the database to it? I have tried quite a few ways, including setting up storage and models for it, but I can't seem to get anything to map to a variable and be usable. I think that is the issue because it seems to work if I'm using a default value for the variable.

Comment: 1. Define all variables: https://prnt.sc/S-K8kH-NnC9A

2. Save the response string to the variable "data" with the TypeScript

3. Run the code this.myHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.data);

4. Use myHTML in the attribute [innerHtml]

5. If it doesn't work - send me a public link to your app - I'll check it

Comment: 2. Save the response string to the variable "data" with the TypeScript --- Are you mapping this to the variable and then running custom TS code? If so, can you show me example code? I've tried a couple ways of doing this and it seems like the code is never run.

Comment: In the success function of any data service you can see the response in the variable "res", so use it to save the value to the variable "data" like this.data = res.myParam;

Comment: I got this to work but needed to use res[0].myParam because it was first returning an array. But doing that as a TypeScript on service success was the missing piece to this. Thanks for your help. Is the res[0] actually what I'm supposed to be doing or is something wrong that I need to do that to get to the data?

Comment: The variable "res" is a general response from the data service. So if your service returns the array with the only item - yes, please use res[0]. If your data service returns a simple object - no need to use "res[0]", use "res". Example: standard database list service returns and array, but the standard database read service returns the object (the only item)